# Error when trying to create a .NET core web project in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

When i try to create a new .NET core 3.0 Web Application project i keep getting  this error

The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) [image]

The error message keeps popping several times even after the project is created and when expanding the solution explorer .

My latest update is 16.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Visual Studio Installer

Click repair

This seems to have solved the problem for me

[image]